# View members of Organizations in Palantir Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry

I am trying to find out if certain Organzations are still reqired on our on-prem stack. I would like to takle this by investigating who is member of such an Organization. Unfortunately we created a LOT of Organizations in the past, going manually through the list of Users does not do the trick. Is there another way which I can use to find out who is member of an Organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to see these requests on the network tab on the https://yourstack.example.com/workspace/settings/organizations webpage if you inspect it. You could write a script locally that calls these (or via a transform if you have admin powers to create non secure projects). Note that the following api endpoints are not documented for general consumption, but nothing prevents you from hitting it.

hitting this api endpoint should give you the organization rids that your token has access to and the user ids included in each org:

```
GET https://yourstack.example.com/multipass/api/organizations/all

Response:
   [
     {"rid": "ri...1", administrators: [userid1, userid2, ...
     {"rid": "ri...2", ...
```

Then you can hit the following endpoint to get the usernames if you need them:

```
POST https://yourstack.example.com/multipass/api/administration/principals
     BODY: [userid1, userid2, ...]
Response:
  {"id":"111111-ffff-aaaa-0000-3131213123","username":"foobar",
```